# MadelineProto Join more than one group/channel at once

Tags: php, telegram, chatbot, telegram-bot

I use MadelineProtoDocs to create a userbot that do tasks I want. What I want to do is that I want to Join more than one group at once!
I have used
`$MadelineProto->messages->importChatInvite(['hash' => 'HASH_CODE']);`

It works when I put a hashcode for one group, but when I put more than one like this:

`$MadelineProto->messages->importChatInvite(['hash' => ['HASH_CODE', 'HASH_CODE2']);`

it doesn’t work

I also tried:

`$MadelineProto->channels->joinChannel(['channel' => [InputChannel, InputChannel], ]);`

it also doesn’t work!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
It’s easy to do that
So when you join a channel or group you do this:

```
$join = yield $MadelineProto->channels->joinChannel(['channel' => '@channelusername', ]);
```

By this you will join only one channel/group,
so how to add another channel/group in the same code?
It’s easy:

```
$join =
yield $MadelineProto->channels->joinChannel(['channel' => '@channelusername', ]);

yield $MadelineProto->channels->joinChannel(['channel' => '@channelusername1', ]);

yield $MadelineProto->channels->joinChannel(['channel' => '@channelusername2', ]);
```

and you will join all the channels you added!